# .net application crash, state of unmanaged resources

Tags: .net

what happens to the unmanaged resources like DB connections, open files,... when a .net application (not web app) crashes

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the resource and how the endpoint for that resource deals with it. For database connections, the database server will listen and wait for any messages for however long it is configured to wait (probably not very long), and then terminate the socket. Files could potentially get stuck in a locked ("being used by another process") state but IME that's extremely rare.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing that happens when a native (C/C++/etc) app crashes.

For the most part, the Operating System will clean up immediately. It will close file handles, mutexes, network connections, and any other stuff that the OS was responsible for.

For other resources not provided by the OS (for example a connection to SQL server), it's up to whichever piece of software is responsible for that resource. As Rex M mentions, SQL server will sit there until the connection times out, and then it will release it, but other third party software may act differently.

This can cause problems if you're getting some unmanaged resource from a crappy piece of third party software, as it may not be smart enough to use timeouts or a similar mechanism, and the unmanaged resource might simply never ever get released.

It can also cause problems if your third party software has long timeouts. For example, if the SQL server connection timeout is 20 minutes, and you crash 20 times in 2 minutes, then you've got 20 "used up" connections sitting there until the timeout happens. You can run yourself out of connections by doing this kind of thing.