# How to be sure an unmanaged resource to be cleaned

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

In my WinCE I have a WinForm:

```
public class SyncForm : Form
{
 IDisposable someResource;
 public SyncForm()
 {
  someResource = new SomeResource();
 }

        private void SyncForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            someResource.Dispose();
        }
}
```

It works fine when application is closing correctly, but the resource is not cleaned if an unhandled exception happens. Where should I put to be sure it is called even if my application crashes?

Comment: _"the resource is not cleaned if [...] my application crashes"_ - the OS manages that.

Comment: @CodeCaster That depends on what exactly the disposable resource is.  Some will get cleaned up eventually, some won't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net application crash, state of unmanaged resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670861/net-application-crash-state-of-unmanaged-resources)

Comment: IDisposable.Dispose() is optional, it is always backed by a finalizer if it isn't called.  If it is critical that your resource is disposed then you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the designer file.  Near the top will be an overridden `Dispose` method.  Dispose of that resource in that Dispose method.  This is the only method in the designer file that is designed to be edited by you, so Visual Studio won't overwrite content you write there.  That said, if you're concerned, you can write a separate method in the normal code behind that you simply call from the `Dispose` method.

Comment: Useful tip: If you move that dispose method from the designer file in to your main file Visual Studio will leave it be in the main file and not regenerate it in the designer file. It makes for easier maintenance.

Comment: I tried this. But the Dispose method is not called in my case :(

Comment: @Solvek If you're not properly disposing of your form then that's a pretty big problem.  You should fix that.  If it's called modelessly then it should be cleaned up automatically.  If you call the form using `ShowDialog` then you need to ensure that it is disposed of manually.  If the app crash is causing a failfast that isn't allowing a "nice" app shutdown then there really isn't anything for you to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that; You have to override the Dispose mehtod from the Form method. Like that:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (disposing)
  {
    if (components != null))
    {
      components.Dispose();
    }

     someResource.Dipose(); //  <-----

    // HERE DISPOSE OTHER STUFF
  }

  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

You can also combined with Finalize/Dispose pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

Your form has to inherit from the `IDisposable` Interface. Then you copy the Dispose method from your Designer file to the form Class and create a boolean Member `bool m_bIsDisposed`.

Then you use the method inherited from `IDisposable` and call `Dispose(bDisposing)`. This is the method you copied from the designer. In the `Dispose(bDisposing)` method you check if the member `bDisposed` is true. If not you dispose your managed objects and set it true.

I've added an example.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Call this Method to Destruct all needed Parts safely.
    /// </summary>
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bDisposing"></param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool bDisposing)
    {
        if (!m_bIsDisposed)
        {
            // Method called first time.        
            if (bDisposing)
            {
                /* Release Managed Objects. If they implement IDisposable, call their Dispose().*/

                try
                {
                    // Events, etc.
                }
                catch { }

                this.StopTimer();
                this.m_Interceptor.Dispose();

                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }

                base.Dispose(bDisposing);
            }
            // Release unmanaged resources (z.B. IntPtr)

        }
        // Set it true, so the method doesn't get called again.     
        m_bIsDisposed = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I resolved this problem

I am releasing resources in Closed event and also in global unhandled exception handler:

```
    public SyncForm()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    }

    private void SyncForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someResource.Dispose();
    }

    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        someResource.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above methods can be applied but you should also consider that in case of an unhandled exception terminating a user-mode process in WinCE all the memory allocated by your application is deleted and all open handles are closed (files and drivers), so no leakage should occour inside the system.